# Enable status bar activity indicator when loading question

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, ios-app

Tapping a question goes to the question's page, initially blank apart from the title and tags.

Quite often this page remains blank for long enough to make me doubt whether it's actually loading or has lost connection or frozen in some way.

If the activity indicator on the status bar were active while it was downloading the content, then I'd feel a lot better about it.

`[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;`

Alternatively, reuse the "Refreshing..." indicator, but with the text changed to "Loading...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There actually is supposed to be a loading indicator on that screen, it just got broken in the 1.3.1 build.  1.3.2 is on its way to the store with an indicator right in the middle of the screen.  I don't like playing with the status bar indicator too much because it is too prone to get stuck in a bad state.